# [ROS2 YAML] Config file without node name

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, yaml, parameters, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to write a YAML parameter file without specifying the ROS2 node name?

The current format for a YAML file is the following:

```
namespace:
    node_name:
        ros__parameters:
            general:
                param_1: 0
                param_2: 'a'
                param_3: 3.14
```

The problem comes when I have a launch file that can dynamically change the namespace and the node_name (multi robot for example). How can the config YAML file be adapted to the dynamic change?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304346/%5Bros2-yaml%5D-config-file-without-node-name/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I found a solution to that.

TL;DR put double asterisk instead of the node name in YAML file.

Elaborate demonstration is on GitHub: https://github.com/yossioo/ros2-yaml-unnamed-node

Feel free to comment is something is unclear.

---

Originally posted by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) with karma: 78 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2020-04-22**:
Thanks for posting that example! This functionality should be available for ROS 2 releases of Dashing and later. (August 2019 and later)

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2020-10-20**:
I'm using this solution without any issue launching "normal" nodes with manual composition.
It is not working instead if I compose the nodes in a container in a launch file.
Is this possible?

**Comment by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) on 2020-10-20**:
Please, share an example that I could run and I will try to check that for you.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2020-10-20**:
I found an issue on Github that confirms my problem: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/715
There are two workarounds but both do not fit my configuration. I'm using Eloquent.